# How to express habitual actions

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

I am learning English Grammar and I learned that I can express habitual actions using present simple and modal like "would". So, are below sentences correct?

- He would come to me every day.
- He comes to me every day.

If both are correct then which one is preferred by linguistics.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct but each means something different.

> He would come to me every day.

Means that he used to come to me every day in the past but doesn't anymore.

> He comes to me every day.

Means he still comes to me every day.